# What is the purpose of capistrano namespacing?

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

In capistrano, when I'm inside a namespace, I can't refer to a task without prepending it by the namespace. So what is the point of the namespaces?

Comment: Don't forget to accept correct answers to your questions. :)

Answer (score 3):

One purpose of namespacing is to avoid naming conflicts, another would be to logically group actions together.